# Combine variadic template arguments with a lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I know what a variadic template is in modern C++, but I can't wrap my head around it to make it possible to write code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


template <typename... Args, typename Combinator>
auto combine(Args... args, Combinator combinator)
{
    auto current_value = combinator(args...);
    return current_value;
}

int main() {
    auto comb = combine(1, "asdf"s, 14.2,
                [](const auto& a, const auto& b, const auto& c) { 
                    stringstream ss;
                    ss << a << "\n";
                    ss << b << "\n";
                    ss << c << "\n";
                    return ss.str();
                });

    return 0;
}
```

In other words I want to give an unknown number of arguments of different types to a function, but the last argument to be a lambda or any callable object used to combine the arguments in some way. The example looks purely academic, but building on this example I want to build more funky code, but first I need this to compile. I hope you can help!

I can't make it compile. I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is what GCC spits:

```
In function 'int main()':
21:6: error: no matching function for call to 'combine(int, std::basic_string<char>, double, main()::<lambda(auto:1&, auto:2&, auto:3&)>)'
21:6: note: candidate is:
7:6: note: template<class ... Args, class Combinator> auto combine(Args ..., Combinator&&)
7:6: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
21:6: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
```

Comment: Why does the lambda/callable have to be the last argument and not the first, which [makes this trivial](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7c42def8ff9461a)?

Comment: First I did it like this and indeed. This is trivial, but the code I'm working on now that uses the construction I proposed is not meant to be generated automatically. It is intended to be written by the user. Specifying the combinator as the last parameter because it is more pleasing to the eye and is more semantically correct. It's much easy to say: `combine this and that with this combinator` instead of `combine with this combinator this and that`

Answer (score 9):

The variadic template must be the last arguments so it can be deduced, see [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

> #### Non-deduced contexts
>
> 7) The parameter P which is a parameter pack and does not occur at the end of the parameter list:
>
> ```
> template<class... Ts, class T> void f1(T n, Ts... args);
> template<class... Ts, class T> void f2(Ts... args, T n);
> f1(1, 2, 3, 4); // P1 = T, A1 = 1: deduced T = int
>                 // P2 = Ts..., A2 = 2, A3 = 3, A4 = 4: deduced Ts = [int, int, int]
> f2(1, 2, 3, 4); // P1 = Ts...: Ts is non-deduced context
> ```

You should change it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


template <typename... Args, typename Combinator>
auto combine(Combinator combinator, Args&&... args)
{
    auto current_value = combinator(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return current_value;
}

int main() {
    auto comb = combine([](const auto& a, const auto& b, const auto& c) { 
                    stringstream ss;
                    ss << a << "\n";
                    ss << b << "\n";
                    ss << c << "\n";
                    return ss.str();
                },
                1, "asdf"s, 14.2);
    std::cout << comb;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> In other words I want to give an unknown number of arguments of different types to a function, but the last argument to be a lambda or any callable object used to combine the arguments in some way.

Since passing the callable as the *last* argument appears key to your question, here's one approach:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename TupT, std::size_t... Is>
    auto combine(TupT&& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::get<sizeof...(Is)>(tup)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupT>(tup))...);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  last element in tuple is the callable
    }
}

template<typename... Ts>
auto combine(Ts&&... ts) {
    return detail::combine(
        std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...),
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>{}
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  arg count = size of pack - 1 (callable)
    );
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b023316ce1d605b)**</kbd>

This also implements perfect forwarding, which was missing from your question's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code indeed can't compile, because variadic template arguments can only be deduced if they're the last parameters.

To do it without changing your interface, you could do something by like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename... Args, typename Combinator>
auto combine_impl(Args... args, Combinator combinator) {
    return combinator(args...);
}

template <typename... Args>
auto combine(Args... args) {
    return combinator_impl<Args...>(args...);
}

int main() {
    auto comb = combine(1, "asdf"s, 14.2,
        [](const auto& a, const auto& b, const auto& c) {
            stringstream ss; ss << a << "\n"; ss << b << "\n"; ss << c << "\n";
            return ss.str();
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

But quite frankly, if just do that:

```
auto comb = [](const auto& a, const auto& b, const auto& c) {
    stringstream ss; ss << a << "\n"; ss << b << "\n"; ss << c << "\n";
    return ss.str();
}(1, "asdf"s, 14.2);
```

And if you can't stand calling and declaring a lambda on the same line, you can use C++17's `std::invoke`:

```
auto comb = std::invoke([](const auto& a, const auto& b, const auto& c) {
    stringstream ss; ss << a << "\n"; ss << b << "\n"; ss << c << "\n";
    return ss.str();
}, 1, "asdf"s, 14.2);
```

Note that the two last versions are faster than the first solution because they keep value types.